# Cython module property

Tags: python, cython, python-c-api, cythonize

In Cython, you can define getter and setter functions for class properties:

```py
cdef class module
  property a:
    def __get__(self):
      cdef int a
      get_a(&a)
      return a
    def __set__(self, int a):
      set_a(&a)
```

Is there a way to define getters and setters at the module level? For example, the syntax might look something like this.

```py
@module_property
def a():
  pass
  
@a.setter
def a(int new_a):
  set_a(&new_a)
  
@a.getter
def a():
  cdef int a_copy
  get_a(&a_copy)
  return a_copy
```

Comment: Probably not. Why not just use a global instance of a class that defines the properties you want?

Comment: Good point. That works fine

Comment: In principle it would be helpful for exposing c-typed module-level variables to Python. It isn't currently supported though I think

Comment: @Brian a similar thing to Python module in C is `namespace`, possible to use variables in namespace instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Brian pointed out, a global instance of a class works great. So it might look something like:

```py
cdef class module: 
  property a:
    def __get__(self):
      cdef int a_copy
      get_a(&a_copy)
      return a
    def __set__(self, int new_a):
      set_a(&new_a)
      
module_instance = module()
```